# Sleeping a PThread other than the one doing the calling

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, sleep, cilk

So I have a bunch of pthreads, where one is the "main" thread and determines if a worker thread should be running or sleeping. But the POSIX definition for sleep says that `The sleep() function shall cause the calling thread to be suspended from execution...`

Obviously I could do something clumsy like have each worker thread check to see if a flag is set, but I'm looking for something a little better. I'm hoping I'm missing something obvious, because this is throwing a wrench in my plans.

Comment: "Stopping" another thread pops up a lot as a question, but it's rarely what you *really* need. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm writing a (hopefully) efficient implementation of a someone's doctoral thesis. The proof depends on certain threads not consuming resources at certain times. To me, that's sleep. If you know a better way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hacking Cilk anyway, I guess you can do whatever you want

How about having each pthread acquire a semaphore unit before dequeueing, (or stealing), a work object, and releasing it after doing the work?  There may be a little latency, sure, but the number of threads available to do work will match the number of units signaled to the semaphore.  To reduce the number of available threads by N from your control thread, wait for and acquire N units, so choking off N work threads.  To start 'em again, signal N units.

Would this work for your system?

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: I *think* so. I hadn't considered using semaphores for that purpose, but it seems like it should do what I want relatively well.

Comment: I guess that, for completeness, I should add that the sema. needs to be created/initialized with the same number of units as there are work threads.  Maybe you could send one unit in the work thread ctor and remove one in dtor, so 'automatically' setting up the sema?

Comment: Ahhh unfortunately I just realized the problem with this. I am not going to be able to stop a thread that is already running. I can stop a thread from doing more work, but I'm not going to be able to stop it mid-run.